# Accessing variables in other Windows Form class C#

Tags: c#

I want to push my var ***selectedDate***  from **frmMain** so it can use in  **frmEvent**.

The var will make a label in frmEvent that var value. Here is my code:

```
private void monthCalendar1_SelectedDate(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedDate = (DateTime.Parse(e.Start.ToShortDateString())).Day;
        frmEvent frmE = new frmEvent();
        frmE.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Is frmMain readonly while in frmEvent? Do you want the current value passed into the form only with the current value the date is at launch? Or can the date change on frmMain and that be reflected in frmEvent?

Comment: selectedMonth grabs the date when the user clicks on it. Should i make frmMain readonly or should i take it off? @NathanWerry

Comment: Nope, was just trying to frame your question with more context.

Comment: So to answer your question if i didnt before it will grab the currrent value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things. Either add a date to the constructor of `frmEvent`, or add a property to `frmEvent` and set it before calling `.Show()`.

Constructor way:

```
public partial class frmEvent : Form
{
  private int SelectedDate;
  public frmEvent(int selectedDate)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    SelectedDate = selectedDate;
  }
}

public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private void monthCalendar1_SelectedDate(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedDate = (DateTime.Parse(e.Start.ToShortDateString())).Day;
        frmEvent frmE = new frmEvent(selectedDate);
        frmE.Show();
    }
}
```

Property way:

```
public partial class frmEvent : Form
{
    public int SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public frmEvent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private void monthCalendar1_SelectedDate(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedDate = (DateTime.Parse(e.Start.ToShortDateString())).Day;
        frmEvent frmE = new frmEvent();
        frmE.SelectedDate = selectedDate;
        frmE.Show();
    }
}
```

Just treat the forms like normal classes, mostly because that is what they are and can be treated as such, do not overthink it.

Comment: I wanted to do the property way but i wasnt sure on how to do it. if you dont my can you give me some code

Comment: Since it is probably a required field for the `frmEvent`, I would probably suggest the constructor way, instead of the property.

Comment: i got an error in frmMain from the line: _**frmEvent.SelectedDate = selectedDate;**_. That reads An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'frmEvent.SelectedDated'

Comment: Whoops, small typo. `frmEvent.SelectedDate = selectedDate;` should be `frmE.SelectedDate = selectedDate;`

Comment: it says 'Cannot implicity type 'int' to 'Sytem.DateTime'

Comment: Did you figure it out? Sorry about the rush just asking

Comment: I updated it while a while ago, should have posted something here I guess. `public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }` changed to `public int SelectedDate { get; set; }`

Comment: no its my fault that i didnt realize that you updated it

Comment: How will I be able to put this in a label thats in frmEvent. Im sorry about all the questions

Comment: You can utilize that property to set what ever you need to after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor. IE. `lblDate.Text = SelectedDate.ToString();`

Comment: the value come back as zero when i click on a date instead of become that date

Comment: I meant to say in the frmEvent_Load event handler, you should put that code, instead of in the constructor. The variable is not set till after the constructor, so you have to put in into the load event.